# How can I run this code on external JS page?

Tags: javascript, gridview

```
<sub>function checkGridView() {
  fNameV = document.getElementById("<%=GridView1.ClientID%>");
  alert(fNameV);
}</sub>
```

When I run it on external JS page `[tag:getElementById]` returns null. how can I fix it?

Comment: what does `<%=GridView1.ClientID%>` render to? If that's in a .js file, you'll need to pre-render it somehow; the JS won't do that.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's something else going on in your code. This seems to be a template (with ASP, maybe?).
For debugging purposes, try to directly use the literal value you expect in `<%=GridView1.ClientID%>` and see what happens. For example:

```js
document.getElementById("GridView1_Id")
```

By the way, give more context about your scenario, for example: where is this GridView coming from? What are the other technologies you're using (.NET, Java...)?